# Vscode randomly remove code when using format on save

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using **format on save** feature in vscode for a while. And sometimes when i save, which invoking **format on save**, vscode randomly remove function and other sentence. I dont have any formatting extension. [Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7K2UR.png). I can just undo but im really afraid its not restore all the code.

Answer (score 0):

It formats on save

Maybe you need to look into your components

for example: Toggle Format on Save